# Data not saving to database properly Django ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I have a webapp with a friends feature, which is all working except for the bit of saving the current user into the requested user's `ManyToManyField`

Here is my model

```py
friends = models.ManyToManyField(User,blank=True,related_name='user_connections')
```

And my view

```py
class AddFriendRedirect(RedirectView):
    def get_redirect_url(self,*args,**kwargs):
        username = self.kwargs.get("username")
        obj = get_object_or_404(UserProfileInfo,slug=username)
        url_ = obj.get_absolute_url()
        user = self.request.user
        if user.is_authenticated:
            print("User is authenticated")
            if user in obj.friends.all():
                obj.friends.remove(user)
                user.user_connections.remove(obj) #this line isnt saving the obj to the database
            else:
                obj.friends.add(user)
                user.user_connections.add(obj) # this line isnt saving the obj to the database
        return url_
```

And finally my urls

`path('profile/<str:username>/add/',views.AddFriendRedirect.as_view(),name='add_friend'),`

Everything is working except for saving for the `user.user_connections.add(obj)`. On `obj.friends.add(user)`, it adds the current user to their Manytomanyfield, but it's just not working on the `user.user_connections.add(obj)` one. I have tried heaps of things, including

`user.friends.add(obj)`

`user.userprofileinfo.friends.add(obj)`

`user.userprofileinfo.user_connections.add(obj)`

> UserProfileInfo is my custom UserProfile model

I am just confused as to why this isn't working, and it's weirder because no errors are being thrown either.
Thanks for any help

Comment: Are you getting an error or is it just not showing up in the database? You could try calling `user.save()`, I think that might be your issue.

Comment: Just added user.save() and it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Could you post your models?

Comment: Is it printing out 'User is authenticated'? And which statement is it hitting, the `obj.friends.remove()`, or the `obj.friends.add(user)`?

Comment: Are `obj` and `user` in the database?

Comment: Yes
`obj.friends.remove(user)` and `obj.friends.add(user)` are both being saved into the database